Anti theft in public place
I'm looking for a way to know if my phone is out of reach on public transportation. Is there a way to force ring or lock the phone when it is away from me using triggers like TWS or other phones via bluetooth?

Maybe you could try an automation option as in here and set whatever action works for you reliably given that public transport can be noisy
